# How to preselect one radio button defaultly

Tags: jsf

When I run my application, "Single User" should be selected automatically.

```
<h:selectOneRadio onchange="showEmailDiv(this.id);" value="" id="emailValue" required="true">   
<f:selectItem itemValue="Single" itemLabel="Single User" />   
<f:selectItem itemValue="Multiple" itemLabel="Multiple User"/>   
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

How can I preselect one radio button defaultly?

Comment: set the default value of your first line to the value you want (Single)

Comment: Thanks Slimu. Colud you please tel me the how to set default value ?

Comment: You just write it in the value tag on the first line

Answer (score 1):

Set default value like this

```
<h:selectOneRadio onchange="showEmailDiv(this.id);" value="Single" id="emailValue" required="true"> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Single" itemLabel="Single User" />     
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Multiple" itemLabel="Multiple User"/>  
</h:selectOneRadio>
```

Note: you aren't binding this component with bean, not sure how would you use it

Comment: Hi Jigar thanks for your reply.. But the above code is not working.

Comment: Can you try debugging based on raw html it generates

Comment: @JigarJoshi how to get value now server side ?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ManagedBean
public class YourBean {
    private String value = "Single User";

    // getter & setter
}
```

And in your page

```
<h:selectOneRadio onchange="showEmailDiv(this.id);" value="#{yourBean.value}" id="emailValue" required="true"> 
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Single" itemLabel="Single User" />     
   <f:selectItem itemValue="Multiple" itemLabel="Multiple User"/>  
</h:selectOneRadio>
```